# Tag badges progress on main user's activity tab

Tags: feature-request, tag-badges, activity-tab

### Issue

The last Stack Overflow update brought us new (and really cool, yay) profile and activity tabs for every user. In the new "Activity" tab, there's now the possibility to track the progress made and needed to earn every regular badge. Nonetheless, I didn't see any tracking option for tag badges. I was a bit confused, and came here on Meta to ask for a feature-request about that, when I noticed that Meta Users actually *have* the option to track tag badges.

### Screenshots

Here are some screenshot to show what I'm actually talking about, in case it wasn't 100% clear.

- Main user:

  [image: main1]
- Meta user:

  [image: meta1]
  [image: meta2]
  [image: meta3]

### Request

My question (and request) is simple: **why do Meta user's activity tabs have got a tag badges tracker, but main user's ones don't?** In my honest opinion, it would also be more helpful to have tag badge trackers on the main site, rather than the Meta site: I wouldn't have blamed the opposite choice, but I'm not a fan of the current one. **Could we implement such a useful feature even on the main SO user's activity tabs?**

Comment: I don't think such a badge tracker is useful. If you are interested in the progress of a tag, you will already know necessary score to reach a badge and will automatically look for it in the tag summary. It might only slightly harder (at least one more click) to see this information if you want to observe a tag that is not under top 10 tags, but who does that?

Comment: @ArtjomB. then why is this tag badge tracker shown on meta? It has already been implemented, and there's a reason behind it. By the way, I do think it's really useful: it displays all the badges with their relative progresses at the same time and makes you save an enormous amount of time instead of searching and trying to figure out how many points/answers you have on every single tag.

Comment: You're right, the dialog itself is useful in that regard, but not the actual selected "watched" tag (I'm interested in multiple tags, not just one).

Comment: @ArtjomB. yes, that could be questionable, but still.

Comment: I have got a "track next tag" option on my main profile here on SO, but not on other sites. There's clearly something else going on here - perhaps if you're "too far away" from the next badge then they don't show?

Comment: @ChrisF I don't think so... look at my last screenshot, I could select any of those badges marking it as "next", but still having 0/0 answers/points. By the way if you're seeing it in your main SO profile that's certainly strange...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli - hmm. There is definitely some reason why it's showing for me (on SO & SU) but not other sites (UX for example).

Comment: @ChrisF some kind of bug? Just saying.. perhaps some SE programmer could answer these questions better :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has been silently taken care of:

[image: screenshot]

Both the main and the meta site have this icon now.

Answer (score 3):

From [the blog post announcing this new feature](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/):

> And the page adapts to serve our most generous users. Once you’ve earned all the privileges, the “next privilege” bar automatically starts tracking your progress toward your closest tag badge (or another one of your choosing).

I don't know a lot about how things work on meta, but the "privilege-earning" thing does not seem to apply here, so I guess it automatically fall-backs to this next step.

Comment: Wow, this is really strange

Comment: Hmm..  I was tracking my next badge on SO, then switched it back to my next privilege, and now don't have the option to go back to my next badge again..  seems a little bit like a bug.